# No wifi adapter found

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

Recently deleted a lot of packages (including network-manager) by mistake (as dependencies) after upgrading to Debian sid. Got somewhat recovered, get wired connection going, but I messed a bit with some configs, (couple of files) and now I get this "no adapter found" thing. I got all the drivers installed and am ready to provide any info, just don't know what to do. I saw other questions like this being answered, but none of those solutions helped.

EDIT1: Some outputs:

```
sudo iw dev
phy#0
Unnamed/non-netdev interface
    wdev 0x2
    addr cc:2f:71:17:34:2e
    type P2P-device
    txpower 0.00 dBm
Interface wlp60s0
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr cc:2f:71:17:34:2d
    type managed
    txpower 0.00 dBm
```

Comment: it seems that I simultaneously got into some dependency hell

Comment: `aptitude` is great to escape from dependency hell, but the UI takes a bit to get used to. First step is to see if wifi adapters are recognized, so do `sudo iw dev`. If you see none, edit question with hardware info of your wifi adapters and `lspci -nn` or `lsusb` (whatever is applicable), and look into `dmesg` after boot for error messages or other reasons why the adapter doesn't get picked up.

Comment: done, wlp60s0 seems to be hardware

Comment: For some reason your `wlp60s0` has a second interface in P2P mode. How did that happen, and do you need it? What exactly goes wrong when network manager tries to use `wlp60s0`?

Comment: I don't know....answer to any of these questions:(

Comment: oh, well, in fact -- it might be the consequence of me messing with some config files, creating my own wpa_supplicant.conf for example.

Comment: I also edited my `/etc/netwrok/interfaces/`

Answer (score 1):

Oh, well, it seems that simply undoing changes I did to configs in `/etc/network/interfaces/` and deleting wpa_supplicant.conf (that I earlier created trying to fix the problem, according to some other advises from SE) did the trick. Nothing much to add here, I suppose.